# How does Spring's InternalResourceViewResolver decide how to parse file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the standard InternalResourceViewResolver:

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
             <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
          </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
      <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

But we are moving away from .jsp's to an MVP architecture using React and jVue  I think,  not my problem :)

Anyway, now that we are using plain HTML,  is there a "plain"  view resolver that simply returns the file without an attempt to parse it?  I can get the InternalResourceViewResolver to serve these files just fine,  but can I get a performance boost with a "plain" view resolver?  I thought I could save time by Spring not even attempting a parse.

Thoughts?

Comment: If the goal is to serve static HTML files, do you need a controller and a view resolver in the first place?

Comment: Yes,  because some of these templates will be coming from a CMS someday and I want to keep that hidden from the fornt-end.  ie,  I want one base url  (like /templates/)  and the front end does not know care how it gets the file

Comment: Then, until the templates actually come from a CMS, why not just put them under templates, where you want them to be?

Comment: Spring, or rather the `InternalResourceViewResolver` or actually the `InternalResourceView` doesn't parse anything. The only thing it does is create a URL based on the `prefix` + `view-name` + `suffix` and next it simply forwards to that URL. It does nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: Then what tells spring to turn a url that has a jsp suffix to run it as a jsp? (Compile it into a servlet and run it)

Comment: Nothing... As stated Spring does only create a url and forwards to that url. After that it is all to the servlet container what to do with that URL.